# org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlArithmetic: bitwiseXor in JEXL sandbox

Tags: jexl

---

I'm working in a native JEXL sandbox, so there is no need of

```
expression e = jexl.createExpression
```

Actually I am able to get this working:

```
foo = new ("org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlArithmetic", false);
tmp = foo.multiply("123","123");
```

with those two lines I can access the var tmp.

Now I want to make a XOR operation like this:

```
tmp2 = foo.bitwiseXor("3","5");
```

This results in an error message as following:

> org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlException: unknown or ambiguous method

any ideas how to make this working?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer by myself ;)
the method bitwiseXor is available only in JEXL version 2.1 and newer.
the version I am using in my sandbox is 2.0, which was a little bit hard to find out.

cheers